# Uninitialized constant YoutubeIt in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a rails(3.0.11) application using youtube_it api. My index action of videos controller contains the basic code of getting the client object:

```
@yt_client ||= YoutubeIt::Client.new(:username => 'my uname', :password => 'my pwd',:dev_key => 'my devkey')
```

I have installed the gem using `gem install youtube_it`, included it in the app's gem file `gem 'youtube_it'` and ran bundle install. But when i restart the server and go to the index page,

i get this **Error**

> "uninitialized constant VideosController::YoutubeIt"

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
YouTubeIt
```

With a capital **T**

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

`require 'youtube_it'`

in either the application controller or in some lib or config file

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo, the correct sintaxis is

```
client = YouTubeIt::Client.new
```

and if you still have problem you can try this way

```
client = ::YouTubeIt::Client.new
```

cheers!