# NameError in WelcomeController#index on RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, controller, webrick

I got this error

```
NameError in WelcomeController#index

uninitialized constant YouTubeIt
Rails.root: C:/Sites/rails_code/youtube
```

Btw i checked the `gem` author `github`, checked sintax of constant, seems everything's alright, so i can't figure it out.

There is a very similar question here:

[Uninitialized constant SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937292/uninitialized-constant-youtubeit-in-rails-application)

But in his case, there was a typo, i don't have any typo, i even checked the tutorial like 6 times, but there's no apparent error on my side, here's my `controller` code:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
def index
    @cliente = ::YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => "AI39si4Ao5BFsYIkbzko7b9A_iktB2Pc8DAblJJ_JzJx6IL6Mju1dYYkMKY6TByz8MJPXfm4__tCAt9Is6Mvjg2JM55kuJVVqQ")
    @videos = @cliente.videos_by(user: "AlbertoMaso2")
  end
end
```

already installed the `youtube_it` and declared it's presence in the app by adding it to the `Gemfile`.

I'm stuck on this one and can't get it to work.

Anyone can shed some light upon this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1-st please check presence of the gem in the 'Gemfile.lock', then try IRB (with bundle exec irb, or rails c): require 'youtube_it'; YouTubeIt

Comment: Yes, it was on the Gemfile.lock indeed, then executed 'rails c require 'youtube_it'; YouTubeIt', after that, 'rails s' on project folder and worked perfectly! Thank you, if you can answer my question with this very same content i can mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: Annoying when tutorials aren't 'complete' hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have changed `Gemfile`, or added a new gem to it, please, make sure that you have updated `Gemfile.lock` also. To update lock file just run `bundle install` command.

Then in order to check usability the gem, you could not run whole rails server, but simply rails console with loaded `development` environment. Do it as follows:

```
$ rails c
```

or

```
$ rails console
```

Then inside the `IRB`, you can try your new gem features, in your case as follows:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'youtube_it'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> YouTubeIt
=> YouTubeIt
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you change

```
@cliente = ::YouTubeIt::Client.new...
```

to

```
@cliente = YouTubeIt::Client.new...
```

Comment: Actually it changes into "uninitialized constant WelcomeController::YouTubeIt" instead of "uninitialized constant YouTubeIt"